# How to calculate CAGR Compound Annual Growth Rate if the starting value is Zero?

Tags: excel, data-analysis, finance

I am trying to calculate the CAGR for the total visitors here. The formula is as follows:
[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izhJQ.jpg)

Now, for the districts where the initial visitors are 0 or Null there there is error showing when calculating the CAGR as we are dividing it by 0.

Please let me know how to avoid this. As even if the initial visitor is 0, there is growth which I want to calculate.

Please help me with this.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXGRp.jpg)

Please let me know how to avoid this. As even if the initial visitor is 0, there is growth which I want to calculate.

Comment: CAGR is not defined if the starting value is 0.

Comment: To elaborate on @z32a7ul comment, you cannot multiply `0` by any percentage and obtain a result other than `0`. You could change your formula to return a result of `#NA`, or you could start your calculation with the first non-zero year.